# Why is unmanaged model not calculating id in Django?

Tags: django, postgresql

I have an unmanaged model in Django:

```
class Person(models.Person):
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = '"public"."person"'
```

Somewhere in my tests, I try to create a Person entry in the DB:

```
person = Person(name="Ariel")
person.save()
```

But then I get an error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "id" of relation "person" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, Ariel).
```

Outside tests, everything works fine. In the tests, I initialize the DB with the tables referenced by the unmanaged by loading a schema dump.

The Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#managed) states that "no database table creation, modification, or deletion operations will be performed for this model", and that "all other aspects of model handling are exactly the same as normal", including "adding an automatic primary key field to the model if you don’t declare it". But doesn't that mean this code should work? How come Django and Postgres are not taking care of the id? Am I doing something wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to declare the `id` field in the model e.g. `id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Surely the issue that you're having is that in your PostgreSQL table, `id` is not an auto incremental field and it nulls by default.

It's quite a common issue when using unmanaged models on Django. You need to cover every single aspect of the table you're using.

Comment: Well, that's the thing, the schema dump that I load in the tests declares the `id` as an auto incremental field. It is a dump from the DB that I use locally, and when I test manually it works. So how come it doesn't it work in the tests?

Comment: In that case I would add `id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)` as the first field in the Person model.